# How do you link local JS and CSS files in a SSR ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

New to ReactJS SSR, I am trying to link local JS files which contains jQuery and CSS files which contains site styles and more importantly media queries. Webpack bundle.js doesn't seem to know these said JS/CSS files.

I have tried adding Link and Script tags into the html template. I have also tried using imports '../path/to/local/file'

webpack: 4.39.1

babel: ^7.5.5

react: 16.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are sending the files to a public directory using `express.static` inside a middleware function in express.

```
app.use(express.static('static-asset-folder'))
```

If you would like to require the use of a specific route in your `href` and `src` paths you can add a specific route

```
app.use('/public', express.static('static-asset-folder'))
```

And you would refernce the files in your tags like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/public/static-assets-folder'>
```